# Do 〜によれば and 〜によると differ regarding the speaker's opinion of the following statement being true?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

From a newspaper:

> 16日の発表**によると**、ドイツ経済の今年の成長率は2.1％、来年が1.8％の見込み。

I think that means:

> According to the report of April 16th, it is expected that the growth of the German economy will be 2.1% this year and it will be 1.8% next year.

So, I am interested in to what degree, if any, the meaning of 〜によると overlaps with the meaning of 〜によれば.

1. 田中氏の発表**によると**、ドイツ経済の今年の成長率は2.1％、来年が1.8％の見込み。
2. 田中氏の発表**によれば**、ドイツ経済の今年の成長率は2.1％、来年が1.8％の見込み。

Here is what I think the difference is:

1. According to Tanaka's presentation, ...
2. If Tanaka's presentation were to be correct, ...

What I would like to know is:

- Do 〜によると and 〜によれば have similar meanings at all?
- Does Ｘによると create the feeling of `Ｘ` being (assumed) true?
- Ｘによれば creates the feeling of subjunctive mood, ie. a feeling of possible doubt about `Ｘ`? It is not assumed to be true?

Does this sound natural and what a newspaper might write?

> 田中氏の発表**によれば**、ドイツ経済の今年の成長率は**2.1％**、来年が1.8％の見込み。でも、松原氏の発表**によれば**、ドイツ経済の今年の成長率は**55.3％**の見込み。

Comment: I think ば does not necessarily mean _if_ and is usually slightly formal when it does not mean _if_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do 〜によると and 〜によれば have similar meanings at all?

Yes, very much so.  In fact, in informal speech between two individuals, the two are largely, if not completely, interchangeable.  We just do not hold each other responsible for word choices like these.

In the media, however, the distinction is made more often and more strictly than in people's daily life for obvious reasons.

> Does Ｘによると create the feeling of Ｘ being (assumed) true?

Yes, it does.  It carries a little more of a resultative nuance than 「Xによれば」 does.  "According to X, A would be B."

> Ｘによれば creates the feeling of subjunctive mood, ie. a feeling of possible doubt about Ｘ? It is not assumed to be true?

Yes, it carries a bit more of a hypothetical nuance than 「Xによると」 does.  "According to X, it seems possible that A might actually be B."

It seems to me that in the media, this distinction is made even more "actively" in writing than in speaking.

> Does this sound natural and what a newspaper might write?

Looks good except for the use of 「でも」, which is way too conversational to use in a newspaper.  They would use  「しかし」.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support the idea of によると and によれば having different nuance? 明鏡国語辞典 treats them as synonymous, as does "A Dictionary of Advanced Japanese Grammar" (Makino and Tsutsui). I actually do feel what you're saying about によれば possibly feeling slightly more hypothetical, but I'm concerned it might just be 気のせい or idiosyncratic. I'd love to hear more about any sources or statistical data you might have on this.