# What's the difference between による and によって?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between による and によって?

Comment: a related post: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23813/do-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0-and-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-differ-regarding-the-speakers-opinion-of-the-following-state

Answer (score 6):

They have the same meaning but different conjugation forms, which means, they merely differ in their ability to connect to other words.

**による**
Since よる is plain (dictionary) form, it's used as a main verb or noun qualifier.

> 遠足に行けるかどうかは天気**による**。
> *Whether we'll be able to go on a picnic **depends on** the weather.*

> 震災**による**被害は甚大だ。
> *The damage **(which brought about) by** the earthquake is immense.*

**によって**
よって is the *te*-form of the verb, so practically it functions as a postposition leading (actually following) a [sentence adverb](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/sentadvqa.htm) clause.

> ヒーローの活躍**によって**世界は救われた。
> ***Thanks to** the hero's efforts, the world is saved.*

If you swap them in a sentence, you'll usually get very different things.

> ウイルス**による**病気を治療する *cure a disease **caused by** viruses*
> (because ～による qualifies the noun 病気.)

> ウイルス**によって**病気を治療する *cure a disease **using** viruses*
> (because ～によって qualifies the predicate 治療する.)

Comment: Obviously correct information, but I *think* the OP may have been asking about the difference when you're using both of them predicatively: 「天気によります。」 vs 「天気によってです。」, for example.

Comment: It seems quite unlikely to me that these two could be used on the equal ground. 天気によってです sounds unnatural outside cleft sentences 「～のは、天気によってです。」. Maybe should I provide the complete conjugation paradigm of による?

Answer (score -1):

「によって」 is like "depending on ..."

「好きな食べ物が人によって違います。」
(It depends on the person what food he/she likes.) or 
(From person to person, it's different on what food he/she likes.)

while 「による」 is like "according to..."

「山口さんによると、アメリカの食べ物がおいしいです。」
(According to Mr. Yamaguchi, American food is delicious.)

Unfortunately I still don't know other uses for the two, though.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? Is this troll downvoting?

Comment: @dotnetN00b as the other answer states, による and によって are just conjugations of the same thing. 「によって」 can also mean "according to" e.g., カントによって、道徳は純粋理性に基づいている。 Related conjugations are よれば　よると (http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1237587592). Consequently, this answer is not very helpful.

Comment: @virmaior I feel that only よれば and よると can translate "according to", though. Expressions for the idea are very idiomatic in both English and Japanese. Your example sounds very unnatural, effectively による ≈ に基づく.